# android: self signed apk can install in emulator but not in device

Tags: android, android-emulator, installation, apk

I wrote a small program and created a signed apk in eclipse kepler.

I cannot install the apk into my device through dropbox with "Unknown source" option UNCHECKED. The option is under Setting -> Security.

However, I can install the apk into my emulator by using

adb install abc.apk

The emulator still got "Unknown Source" UNCHECKED.

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

Regards,

Antony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will also work via ADB on the actual device while unknown sources is unchecked.

However, if you want to install the APK right from your device using a file management app, you will have to enable installations from unknown sources.